# How can I prevent database abuse while still maintaining an open database in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Say I have a website that lists gadgets.

There is a collection that lists all the drones. I leave this collection open to reads, To ensure Google crawls my website and that every user visiting can read all the drones without the need to signin/signup.

My worry though is that someone one day will find the database endpoint or sth and start fetching the whole collections costing me for the reads.

How can i get around this. Or how would websites with open data e.g newssites or ecommerce websites go about this. Considering they are using Firestore for it's great querying capabilities

Comment: Sounds like you need rate limiting and to limit the result set to a certain number of results

Comment: Another approach is aggressively caching / using a CDN, to reduce the impact on your origin server.

Answer (score 3):

The title of your question pretty much is already in contradiction with itself.  "Open database" pretty much implies "potential for abuse".

If you want to stop the potential for abuse entirely, you have to close the database and control all access to it.  With Firestore, that means shutting down all direct access using security rules, and forcing all access through a backend you control.  Your backend will have to decide on a per-request basis if the request should actually query the database.

Even then, the endpoint that you open up for your API can still be abused, albeit at a (probably) lower cost.

The problem you're describing is universal to all systems that choose to expose public endpoints.  One you have an public endpoint, there is potential for abuse, and only your cloud provider can help shut it down at that point. So, if you suspect abusive behavior, you should contact your cloud provider directly to report it.

Comment: will google reduce the bill caused by protentional abuser ? I think firestore should implement such a feature that will limit number of request/min or at least set a solution that will point out to user account that is using a lot of unreasonable resources so it can be tackle, firebase is an awesome product, the only thing that is bugging me is lack of counter measures.  I hope this will be tackled in future.... it is really necessary, betting on the low chance of a potential abusers but in the modern web betting don't have a place here, especially since lets say mongo don't have those issues,