# Misuse: Reverse Engineering a Flutter App and Infinite read request

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am about to finalize my Flutter App and release it. As a database I use Firebase right now. I set up my security rules and everything is implemented as described in the security checklist.

In the security rules I always check if the user is logged before allowing a read request.

My question is: If somebody wants to hack me and reverse engineer my app and find the point where the (fake)user is already logged in and just add an infinite loop with read request, what would happen?

From my understand he will be still logged in with his fake account and has a hacked apk file and if he run the hacked apk file he will sent infinite read loop to my firebase project and I get a expensive billing.

Can this happen or is it not possible for the hacker to compile the apk in a way that he can use it after hacking again?

I searched in the internet, but didn't find any specific answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

> If somebody wants to hack me and reverse engineer my app and finde the point where the (fake)user is already logged in and just add an infinite loop with read request, what would happen?

Exactly what you said will happen: an infinite loop with read requests will happen, and you will be billed for it.

Google Cloud products have some level of abuse control built into them. It's possible that they will detect and stop abusive behavior, but probably only at large scale.

The only viable ways you can mitigate abuse on your own is to:

- Use [AppCheck](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) to cut down on abusive behavior.
- Place limits on what the user can do (which usually involves not letting them have direct access to your database, and make them go through an API endpoint that you control which does rate limiting).

It's not possible to fully eliminate abuse.  This is part of the expense of running a service that's publicly available over the internet - everyone has access to it, and can reverse engineer it.

See also other similar questions:

- [Preventing Abuse: Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333886/preventing-abuse-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
- [How can I prevent database abuse while still maintaining an open database in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143825/how-can-i-prevent-database-abuse-while-still-maintaining-an-open-database-in-fir)
- [Firestore: prevent abuse from public apiKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011119/firestore-prevent-abuse-from-public-apikey)
- [Does Firebase Firestore have measures to stop malicious requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736855/does-firebase-firestore-have-measures-to-stop-malicious-requests)